# Showing all directories and files, also readable writable and executable

Tags: unix

```
#!/bin/sh

LOCATION=$1

if [ "$#" -ne "1" ]
then
echo "Usage: test1 <directory_name>"

else
echo "Number of directories:` find -type d | wc -l `"
echo "Number of files: ` find -type f | wc -l`"
echo "Number of readable:` find -perm -g+r | wc -l`"
echo "Number of writable:` find -perm -g+w | wc -l`"
echo "Number of executable:` find -perm -g+x | wc -l`"
fi
```

is there anything wrong with this code? I want it to show all the directories, files readable, writable, and executable when i type in ./test1

Comment: What is your question actually about? Does your code work or not? Anything that should be different? Why don't you name your problem? What output _do_ you get?

Comment: Number of directories: 1
Number of files: 5
Number of readable: 6
Number of writable: 0
Number of executable: 1
 Sorry that is the out put, number of writable is always 0, don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `LOCATION` in `find` command. If you didn't give any value, then it will start to find files from current directory and recursively.

Your script should be like,

```
#!/bin/bash 
LOCATION=$1

if [ "$#" -ne "1" ]
then
   echo "Usage: test1 <directory_name>"    
else
   echo "Number of directories: $(find $LOCATION -type d | wc -l)"
   echo "Number of files: $(find $LOCATION -type f | wc -l)"
   echo "Number of readable:$(find $LOCATION -perm -g+r | wc -l)"
   echo "Number of writable: $(find $LOCATION -perm -g+w | wc -l)"
   echo "Number of executable: $(find $LOCATION -perm -g+x | wc -l)"
fi
```